# Laravel API not accepting JSON request from Postman

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, postman

Laravel API is not accepting JSON request. If I request as form-data it works but if I post JSON object in postman body then it does not receive the request data.

Route:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'imp'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->group(['prefix' => 'lead'], function () use ($router) {
        $router->post('/jardy', 'FeedController@jardy');
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
 public function jardy(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'api_key' => 'required',
        ]);
        $api_key = $request->input('api_key');
        return $api_key;
}
```

`JSON` Request:

[image: Postman request using JSON]

Form data Request:

[image: Postman request using Form data]

Why its not working in case of `JSON`, `content-type` is `application/json`, `Accept:*/*`???

Comment: does `$request->validate([ 'api_key' => 'required' ])` work?

Comment: yes its working, when i use form-data it works.  its like ```$this->validate($request, [
            'api_key' => 'required',
        ]);```. You have nissed ```$request```.

Comment: Can you try `->validate($request->all()` instead of `->validate($request`

Comment: ``` validate ``` method expects ```Request``` object. It shows error when i modify like you are suggesting. @Dilip Hirapara

Comment: Notice I am using the `validate` method on `$request` not on `$this`

Comment: @apokryfos ```validate``` method on ```$request``` shows  ```error: Request::Validate does not exist```.

Comment: What laravel version are you using?

Comment: @apokryfos ```Laravel  Framework Lumen (5.7.8) (Laravel Components 5.7.*)```

Comment: That's odd, but you can also try `$this->validate($request->all(), [...])` sidenote, the `$request->validate` macro is registered via the [`FoundationServiceProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/FoundationServiceProvider.php) so you can also check if that's registered. Not sure if Lumen registers that by default

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comments are not permitted in JSON.
There's a bug in the field Body -> raw -> json

Comment: thanks. It's too foolish error for me

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the header

Accept: application/json

Then laravel parses your RAW json as input vars and they can be accesed with ->input()

see:
[image]

using */* which is the postman default, will not work..
If you dont want to relay on the header, you could also do `$request->json()` but i guess, you just want to pass the header.

See the source that handles this:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithContentTypes.php#L52

and
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithContentTypes.php#L32

Comment: You are right, there is something I am doing wrong in Postman, Now I hit the API from an angular application, its working perfectly fine.

Comment: Of course Content-Type should also be application/json, as you suggested yourself in the original post. / You could inspect the request in your browser to see which headers your angular app is sending..

Comment: Did you disable the default *\/\* ?, I am pretty sure it only needs Accept and Content-Type headers, by default...

It's also required to have laravel output json errors instead of html

Comment: I added 2 links to the source, that is handling this...

Comment: thank you @Danny, ```isJson()``` returns ```true```, but error is still the same when called from Postman.

Comment: @gs-design solution resolve the solution, it was the comments in the json objects, when i removed the comments, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was lack of `Content-Length` header.

Value should be a number of characters of request body.

`Content-Type: application/json` also should be present.

Answer (score 0):

I think its important to note that invalid json might be the problem here. In my case I was using postman variables and had to enclose them in double quotes

earlier I did `{"client_id": {{client_id}}}` and so when I changed to `{"client_id" : "{{client_id}}"}` it worked for me. Hope this helps